# Probability - calculating the odds of getting a certain number of instances.

Tags: probability

In a game I'm making I'm creating a certain economy system, in order to make the economy system work correctly I need to calculate the probability of something which I'm not sure how to:

If I have 10 card types that a player can get, (different card types) and the player gets to pull out of an endless deck 10 random cards (with equal odds for each card type of the various types), what is the probability that the player has 3 or more of the same card type.

My initial thought was - if it were 3 card pulls then it will probably be 1C10 * 1C10 * 1C10 (where C stands for choose) but since he gets more than 3 pulls how do I accommodate for that?

My second thought was creating a decision tree, each degree in the tree has 10 possibilities, and I need to take into consideration all paths from the root to the lowest level that contain 3 or more choices of a specific card and multiply it by 10, but I cant seem to think of a formula for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $i=1,\dots,10$ let $E_i$ denote the event that $3$ or more cards of type $i$ are pulled out.

Then to be found is:$$P(E_1\cup\cdots\cup E_{10})$$

For this we can use the inclusion/exclusion principle in combination with symmetry.

Evidently $P(E_1\cap\cdots\cap E_k)=0$ if $k>3$, so we arrive at:$$P(E_1\cup\cdots\cup E_{10})=\binom{10}1P(E_1)-\binom{10}2P(E_1\cap E_2)+\binom{10}3P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)$$

So it remains to find:

- $P(E_1)$
- $P(E_1\cap E_2)$
- $P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)$

These probabities can be found on base of multinomial distributions. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_1, \ldots, T_{10}$ be the $10$ card types. We calculate the number of ways in which $10$ random cards can be drawn such that the number of cards of all types are always less than or equal to $2$.

Let a draw of $10$ random cards is done and the number of cards of the type $T_i$ be $X_i$. Then we need to compute the number of possible combinations of $X_i$'s such that,

$$X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_{10} = 10, \ \ 0 \leq X_i \leq 2$$

This number will be the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in,

$$(1+x+x^2)^{10} = \sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{i}x^i(1+x)^i = \sum_{i=0}^{10}\sum_{j=0}^{i}\binom{10}{i}\binom{i}{j}x^{i+j}$$

which will be,

$$N =\sum_{\substack{i=0, j=0\\i+j=10}}^{10,i}\binom{10}{i}\binom{i}{j} \\= \binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5} + \binom{10}{6}\binom{6}{4} + \binom{10}{7}\binom{7}{3} + \binom{10}{8}\binom{8}{2} + \binom{10}{9}\binom{9}{1} + \binom{10}{10}\binom{10}{0} = 8953$$

The required probability will then be,

$$\frac{10^{10}-8953}{10^{10}}$$